# Extending existing spring jpa repository functions

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring to communicate with mysql db.
I've got an Entity class and an interface that extends CrudRepository.
Everything works great - read/write etc.

I want to 'extend' the findAll methods. I want to manipulate the received data from findAll before returning it.

user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User
{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String type;

    getters/setters
}
```

repo:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {  
    List<User> findAll();
    Map<String, String> afterManipulatedFindAllData();  
}
```

I want that afterManipulatedFindAllData() will manipulate findAll data as I like.

Is that possible?

**added**
after reviewing @BoristheSpider link:

```
interface UserRepository {
  Map<String, String> afterManipulatedFindAllData();
}

class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository{

    public Map<String, String> afterManipulatedFindAllData() {
        ////how this method receive the 'findAll' data?//////
    }
}

public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserRepository  
{   
    List<User> findAll();
    Map<String, String> afterManipulatedFindAllData();  
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Avi

Comment: Well, yes. Write a method, call findAll() inside this method, and do whatever you want with the result.

Comment: ` to manipulate the received data`. Can you say more about the manipulation you are looking for?

Comment: Yes - for example you can [add fragments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

Comment: @JBNizet I think the issue the OP is having is that Spring generates the code from an `interface` - so there is no `class`. The link I referenced demonstrates how to add fragments to the Spring repos.

Comment: I still want to use the repository class.
@BoristheSpider I saw this link before, what I'm missing is how those functions receiving the results

Comment: @AviElgal I don't understand your question. Methods (not functions) always recieve results in the same way. I would suggest a more careful reading of the documentation.

Comment: @AviElgal to get the best answer, ask a better question. Give a concrete example of what you want to achieve. What is the entity? What is the signature and return type of the method you want to add? What should it do, precisely?

Comment: example added to the original question

Comment: It's still unclear what the Map<String, String> is supposed to be. But this method should probably just not be inside the repository. It should be part of your business logic, inside a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can always define new methods in the repository by specifying a JPA query for them:

```
@Component
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {

    public List<User> findByEntityStatus(EntityStatus status);

    @Query("from User user left outer join fetch user.areas where user.code = :code")
    public User findByCode(@Param("code") String code);
}
```

Maybe this could work for you?

Comment: That works for query methods - but to add arbitrary behaviour you need to use extension fragments.